# Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1

Tags: apex, error

Getting an error in apex code and quite new to apex code.

> Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column
>   -1

Following is the code:

```
public class TotalAmountUpdate {
   public static void TotalAmountUpdate (Construction_Linked_Schedule__c[] TAPNEW) {
      for (Construction_Linked_Schedule__c C :TAPNEW) {
          List<C.Contruction_Linked_Schedule__c> allFlatids =  [SELECT C.Flat_Id__c , C.Total_Amount_Paid__c FROM Construction_Linked_Schedule__c ];

          for (C.Construction_Linked_Schedule__c.FLAT_ID__C currentFlat_id : allFlatids) {

              Decimal FFSPayment = (Decimal)[Select SUM(C.Total_Amount_Paid__c)FFSTOT from C.Construction_Linked_Schedule__c where C.Milestone_number__c < = 2][0].get('FFSTOT'); 

                  If ( C.Milestone_number__c = 2)  { C.Total_Amount_Paid__c = FFSPayment ; }
                  Update C.Total_Amount_Paid__c ;
          } 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of code syntax issues. Lets see if we can explain those to you:

```
public class TotalAmountUpdate { 
    public static void TotalAmountUpdate (Construction_Linked_Schedule__c[] TAPNEW) { 
       for (Construction_Linked_Schedule__c C :TAPNEW) {

            List allFlatids = [SELECT **Flat_Id__c**,**Total_Amount_Paid__c** FROM Construction_Linked_Schedule__c ];
            for (Construction_Linked_Schedule__c currentFlat_id: allFlatids) {
                 //Decimal FFSPayment = (Decimal)[Select SUM(C.Total_Amount_Paid__c)FFSTOT from C.Construction_Linked_Schedule__c where C.Milestone_number__c < = 2] [0].get('FFSTOT');

                //If ( C.Milestone_number__c = 2) { 
                      //C.Total_Amount_Paid__c = FFSPayment ; 
               // }

               //Update C.Total_Amount_Paid__c ; 
           }
        } 
     }     
 }
```

You do not need to use the dot notation to access the fields in a select statement. running:

```
[SELECT Id,Name,Address FROM Account]
```

is a valid query.

When creating a list of a certain type you need to denote the Object it is a list of:

```
list<Construction_Linked_Schedule__c> constructionLinkedSchedule = new list<Contruction_Linked_Schedule__c>();
```

Looking at the number of syntactically incorrect statements - it maybe worthwhile for you to review the documentation for syntax in apex.

Link: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf

Comment: This is also an incorrect boolean expression:
if( C.Milestone_number__c = 2)
It should be:
 if(C.Milestone_number__c == 2)